# ColdFusion pages hang, but only after loading content

Tags: coldfusion

We have a Windows server running ColdFusion 8.  When I load a CF page from that server in a browser, the page content is displayed almost immediately, but the connection does not close.  The browser's "page loading" icon keeps spinning for another ten seconds.

I did a test where I created two files: test.cfm and test.html and loaded them side by side on the server.  Each file contains only a single line of text: "This is a test."  When I load each page in a browser, both pages display the text immediately, but only the CF page keeps "loading" for another ten seconds.

This behavior is making our AJAX-driven pages unusable. What is causing this behavior, and how I can fix it?

Comment: Thanks for the initial comments.  The problem is not occurring on our development server, only on the production server, so it seems like a ColdFusion server issue or a connection issue, not a code issue.  And it happens with all CF pages, not just AJAX.  I have limited access to the Prod server, so I have not been able to restart or enable debugging.  I will report back if/when I am able to try your suggestions.

Comment: It turns out that this error only happens when connected to the network via VPN.  (The application runs on an intranet.)  The users who are on the network directly do not see this behavior. So that is good news, but I'd still like to know the cause.

Answer (score 0):

There must be some code in there trying to do something. And it may not be in the page itself, it could be in an include or the application file.

That type of spinning cursor behaviour sounds like some sort of ajax call failing after the initial page load.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that would help is to turn on ColdFusion debugging and post the results here.

ColdFusion and Ajax, out of the box work very well together, and ColdFusion has an almost insanely simple page debugging tool that make it extremely easy to see the execution path of the CFM file and where the page is spending its time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you restarted the CF service? If there are already hung requests or other problems then that will likely be the only way to resolve.